How do I handle a crash of a Golang (Gin) web server and recover with a new process?
I am in the process of writing a bunch of APIs. I am going to use Gin.
I will deploy behind a reverse proxy (I am forced to use Apache).
Like any process, I expect the Gin process to crash from time to time.
How would I spawn a new instance of my app when this happens?
When I worked with PHP (before fpm) there was mod_php and Apache would create a new worker instead of a crashed one.
What is the current approach to this?
I am deploying to a server using Redhat 9.4

do you use ubuntu?

Either use systemd, or Windows service where the automatically restart the proc

I deploy on Redhat

You could do two things:
First, you could catch panics and restart the listener - something I wouldn't recommend.
Otherwise it depends on the system your API server is running on.
Kubernetes, Docker, Docker Compose, Linux,Windows and macOS all have mechanisms to restart crashed processes.
Additionally, Kubernetes and Docker Compose enables you to write health checks to restart processes that are not crashed, but are unresponsive.

I will be using Docker to deploy. So u sing the Docker tools for health checks and watchdog are the preferred way? When I do node, I use PM2, for example, Do I understand Go does not have something similar?

You can use Docker or PM2 if you want. PM2 is in no way tied to node applications, there is also nothing special about Go applications that makes specific tools a requirement.
